# Confusing behaviour unpacking iterable containing non-numeric values

Tags: python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

When trying to unpack some lists in a larger program I run into the following problem:

```
>>> l = ['b',1]
>>> x,y = l

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

However, I can easily unpack a list of all integer values.

```
>>> l = [0,1]
>>> x,y = l

x = 0
y = 1
```

I have no clue as to what the problem is... The first list is clearly of length 2 so I should be able to unpack it into two variables?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; your code is working for me.

Comment: @DanielGiger I'm using python 3.8 if that makes any difference

Comment: I tried it in 3.7 and 3.8, and it worked in both with no errors.